# sql: show only the max count (php)

Tags: php, html, sql, count, max

I have been scrolling through various examples but can't seem to get the right answer. What I am trying to get here is to display:
staffID,name from Table Staff
total no. of tasks that the staff is involved in from StaffWorksInTask
(Only with the staff that is involved with most number of task)

Staff: staffID, name

StaffWorksInTask: staffID, taskID, projectID

What I did as a first step was to neglect the filter part:

```
SELECT COUNT(W.staffID), S.staffID, S.name 
FROM Staff S, StaffWorksInTask W 
WHERE S.staffID = W.staffID 
GROUP BY W.staffID
```

But now I am just completely stuck with the condition that can make the list only show the staff with the most tasks involved (So that, the other staff are not shown).
Please help!! Much appreciated!!

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." You're doing the opposite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit result

`SELECT COUNT(W.staffID) as total, S.staffID, S.name FROM Staff S, StaffWorksInTask  WHERE S.staffID = W.staffID GROUP BY S.name,S.staffID ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: hi...the problem is not that it doesn't works...it works fine, but i needa get it so that only the one staff with the most count of tasks is shown, thanks...

Comment: hi Jonny B, Its corrected as per as your requirement

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to see only one, top result?

You could do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(W.staffID) as counter, S.staffID, S.name 
FROM Staff S, StaffWorksInTask W 
WHERE S.staffID = W.staffID 
GROUP BY S.staffID 
ORDER BY counter DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

This will display just one staff member – the one who has the most tasks

`ORDER BY` clause sorted the results in descending order by count of tasks,

`LIMIT` clause makes sure you see only 1 result (starting from row 0)

Answer (score 0):

As @jarlh says, you've got your grouping back-to-front.

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(W.staffID) as c, S.staffID, S.name 
FROM Staff S, StaffWorksInTask W 
WHERE S.staffID = W.staffID 
GROUP BY S.staffID, S.name
ORDER BY c DESC
```

The precise syntax may vary - you didn't specify which database platform you were working with.

Comment: hi...the problem is not that it doesn't works...it works fine, but i needa get it so that only the one staff with the most count of tasks is shown, thanks...